# pandas groupby join data with"|" but exclude null,nan,emptystring,whitespace

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

here is the sample data for my question

| pid | date | task | language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8522 | 17-09-2022 | listen | english |
| 7851 | 17-09-2022 | read | hindi |
| 7546 | 17-09-2022 |  | telugu |
| 3584 |  | write |  |
| 8522 | 18-09-2022 | read |  |
| 7851 | 19-09-2022 |  | hindi |
| 8522 |  | speak | hindi |
| 7546 | 19-09-2022 | speak | english |
| 3584 |  | write | tamil |
| 8522 | 25-09-2022 |  |  |

i tried to code and got the output

`data=df.groupby('pid')[['date','task','language']].transform(lambda x: '|'.join(x))`

and i got this output

image1:-[image: output given by the code]

and i want the output to be with no empty/null values to be added so my desired final output would look like this but i have not idea how to filter or remove the values and get the output

image2:-[image: my final output]

any answer or suggestion is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) in the lambda expression before joining.

Here is what works for me:

```
out = (
    df
    .groupby('pid')[['date','task','language']]
    .agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x
                            .replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
                            .dropna()
                            .astype(str)
                           )
        )
)
print(out)
```

```
                                  date               task        language
pid                                                                      
3584                                          write|write           tamil
7546             17-09-2022|19-09-2022              speak  telugu|english
7851             17-09-2022|19-09-2022               read     hindi|hindi
8522  17-09-2022|18-09-2022|25-09-2022  listen|read|speak   english|hindi
```

Comment: it helps with the solution but what if it contains whitespace instead of null/empty values what should I change in the code then

Comment: I updated the solution which replaces cells which contains whitespace (and only whitespace) with `np.nan`.